# Perform an action when the Escape key is pressed (sheet)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

In my code, I have a sheet. There are two buttons inside, each returning an essential value; however, the sheet can be closed by Escape. So I'm looking to perform an action when pressed this key is pressed, to return a value in every case.

Here's my code: the compiler the compiler gets stuck and doesn't build my app...

```
VStack {
// some content
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
// some content
})
.onKeyPress { key in
    if key == .escape {
         NSApplication.shared.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: false)
    }
}
```

Same issue:

```
VStack {
// some content
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
     VStack {
     // some content
     }
     .onKeyPress { key in
         if key == .escape {
              NSApplication.shared.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: false)
         }
     }
})
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "returning an essential value"? Can you show more of the code of the sheet to show *how* you are "returning a value"?

Comment: It an important variable important for me, but there's no link with my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the escape key in a sheet is the same thing as dismissing the sheet so implement a closure/function for the `onDismiss` parameter

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: {
    // handle dismiss
}, content: {
    // some content
})
```

Comment: This is such a good example of the SwiftUI philosophy. "Handle the escape key being pressed" is the implementation detail, but the framework exposes it as the more abstract term "abstract", which could mean a swipe-away on mobile.